# Dynamic determination for database

Tags: quarkus-panache

I have some entity mapping to a collection in a mongoDB.  However, I have a separate database I want the same code to run against (eg. Constants.db_B).  How can I make this parameter dynamic so I can run this without changing the constant and recompiling?  If I could pass this as a parameter that would be fine too.

```
@MongoEntity(collection = "sample", database = Constants.db_A)
public class SomeEntity extends PanacheMongoEntity {
}
```

I tried using ConfigProperty on the Constants class, but it only injects it on a bean instance and not the class itself.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible right now. This has been issued in the quarkus project.
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/14789

It's not the same casuistry than yours but there's a solution made from the Author of that issue, may be helpful for you
https://gitlab.com/ch3rub1/quarkus-mongo-mutitenant

Comment: Thank you for identifying this limitation.